# Is it possible to connect an HP 1760 SCSI Tape to a regular NON server board PC?

Tags: backup, hp, scsi, tapedrive, lto

I own an Ultrium HP Tape 1760 SCSI, that used to reside on a Dell 2850, on an LSI SCSI card.

That Server is now R.I.P. Sad to say.

I want to connect the Tape to another PC, is it possible? 
What card do I need? 
A specific MOBO maybe?

- Ignoring the speed loss, as I use this as a backup tool overnight only.

Comment: Just a heads up that asking if it can be done is on topic but asking for products is considered to be a "shopping" question, which is off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [HP Ultrium 1760 is a SAS or SCSI-capable tape drive unit](http://h18006.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12128_div/12128_div.html#Models). Product #EH920A is SAS and #EH922A is SCSI.

Your ability to connect it to a non-server or non-HP system depends on the HBA available to you.

In this case, the path of least resistance is to move the HBA from the server to your replacement system. Otherwise, you can purchase a compatible SCSI controller. HP recommends and rebrands the LSI SAS and SCSI HBA line for tape drive use.

For SCSI, the [HP #412911-B21 SC11Xe](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/proliantstorage/adapters/sc11xe/index.html) controller is the same as the LSI LSI2030IE. It's a good option for a single-channel U320 SCSI controller. That's what I would recommend if your existing HBA doesn't work in your replacement server/workstation.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIR HP 1760 is not "plain" SCSI, it is SAS. But in any case you just need an appropriate [SCSI/SAS controller](http://www.pc-pitstop.com/sas_controllers/) to fit in a PCI/PCIx slot on your motherboard.

Comment: The Ultrium 1760 can be SAS or SCSI.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that you can connect absolutely any tape drive to a regular PC provided you can obtain a suitable controller card that will work with the PC hardware and operating system. Indeed, many of us use regular PCs to test such setups (generally using a server OS on the PC) before moving them onto production servers.